# Why does this program give an error when run

Tags: java

Can someone tell me why, when I run the program shown below, I get an error (shown below code)

```
public class Main{
  Node next = null;
  int data;

  public void Node(int d) {
    data = d;
  }

  void appendToTail(int d) {
    Node end = new Node(d);
    Node n = this;
    while (n.next != null) {
        n = n.next;
    }
    n.next = end;
  }
}

Node node1 = new Node(5);

node1.appendToTail(7);
```

I got this error that said something about class, enum, or interface expected. Can someone explain what this means and what I have to do to my code?

```
Main.java:19: error: class, interface, or enum expected
Node node1 = new Node(5);
^
Main.java:21: error: class, interface, or enum expected
node1.appendToTail(7);
^
2 errors
compiler exit status 1
```

Comment: You can't have code outside of a class or an enum.

Comment: Your `Node` is currently structured as a method. The compiler expected you to have it as a class/enum/interface since you used it as a variable.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you provided. It looks like you are trying to create linked list.

There are several issues with the program

1. Name of the class needs to be `Node` instead of `Main` otherwise `node1.appendToTail(17)` will not work
2. Lines of code outside a `class`, `interface` or `enum`.

```java
Node node1 = new Node(5);
node1.appendToTail(7);
```

These lines must be inside any of the above three mentioned. For this question, it must be inside the `main` method of `Node` class.

3. Constructor doesn't have a return type.

```java
  public Node(int d) {
    data = d;
  }
```

**Final Result**

```java
class Node {
  int data;
  Node next;

  public Node(int d) {
    data = d;
  }

  void appendToTail(int d) {
    Node end = new Node(d);
    Node n = this;
    while (n.next != null) {
        n = n.next;
    }
    n.next = end;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node node1 = new Node(5);
    node1.appendToTail(7);   
  }

}
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help!